# Hiding default controller name in PHP CodeIgniter URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the default controller name from URLs in CodeIgniter using htaccess; I have hidden index.php but also want rid of the default controller which is currently called con_index.

For example if site root was mysite.com,
mysite.com/con_index/function1 would change to mysite.com/function1 and so on.

All other controllers can remain in the url, so if I had another controller called locations with a function called location1, mysite.com/locations/location1 would stay the same.

I think this makes for a more conventional structure rather than a class and function name popping in there the second you leave the site root. Gnashed my teeth trying to achieve this, can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you just create a controller called "function1" and leave the "con_index" controller only for your home page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ index.php/com_index/$1 [nc] [L]
```

This would replace any occurrences inside brackets with `$1`. So, when you're calling `www.example.com/function_1/` it actually calls `www.example.com/com_index/function_1`

However, I'm not sure it works for CI because CI might have some restrictions for accessing the URL Route.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'con_index'
```

[CodeIgniter Default Controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#default)

Comment: Yes, that's already there. I don't want it to appear in the URL string though.

Comment: Here is an idea, but not sure it works. Go to : application/config/routes.php and add: $route['/(:any)'] = "con_index/$1";

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid, I've been trying to do similar thinks in htaccess without success. I only need to hide my default controller con_index, the others can remain.

Comment: I've had a play, and can get the effect I want by adding $route['function1'] = 'con_index/function1' to routes.php. However I would need a rule like this for every function/page off the default controller. Not the best solution, can anyone do any better?

Comment: As CodeIgniter has support for regular expressions in it's url mapping, you can try something like this : `$route['^(?!admin|login).*'] = “con_index/$0″;` . Now all you have to do is replace admin or login with the controllers you want not the match your mapping. Just separate them with | in between.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`$route['(:any)'] = 'controller_name/function_name/$1';

it will replace controller and then u can try to access url by not putting controller name in it.